# Habilitar botões para windows , e Windows 32 e 64 Bits

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, preciso da ajuda de vocês pois estou com um problema relacionado a este código, nele a principio preciso distinguir qual Windows a pessoa usa, e se ele é
32 ou 64. Porém não sei oque há de errado, sou novata nessa área, poderiam me ajudar?

Código:

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Teste</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var OSName = "";
    function sistema(){
        if((window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1)&&
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('32')!= -1)){
         OSName = "Windows 10 --> 32bits";}
        else if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= 
-1)&&(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('64')!= -1){
         OSName = "Windows 10 --> 64bits";} 

         alert(OSName);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="sistema()">
    <input type="submit" name="Teste" value="Teste" 
onclick="javascript:sistema();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta linha está errada:

```
else if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1)&&(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('64')!= -1){
```

Pode trocar para:

```
else if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('64')!= -1) {
```

Outra coisa que talvez te ajude, você já tem as informações no próprio objeto. Veja se isso já não resolve pra você:

```
alert(navigator.oscpu);
```

Comment: Nosssaaa, muitooo obrigadaaaa... Você ajudou demaiss, Obrigada de verdade, Valleuuu

Answer (score 0):

Falta um par de parenteses no seu else if
Ficando assim:

```
else if((window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 10.0")!= -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('64')!= -1)){
```

Porem pelo que vi vc terá o OSName somente se for Windows 10. Se for outra versão ele não vai retornar nada nessa variável. Ai tem que ver a sua necessidade, se é isso mesmo que vc precisa.

Comment: Obrigada de verdade, Valleuuu